# Xcode: name clickable in UITextField and launch addressbook upon click

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

In the following UI, you can select person from address book. Notice that name is clickable and launches address book upon click.

[image]

In my application, I am able to choose contact from address book and extract the full name but when I add it to UITextField, it just shows as name, its not clickable as follows:

[image]

```
Q. How can I make the name in my app clickable and it would take me to address book upon click.
```

I am using wrapper classes to interact with address book and here is my code.

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:
(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
      shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
                                property:(ABPropertyID)property
                              identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier
{
    // Guaranteed to only be working with e-mail or phone here
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    NSArray *array =
    [ABContact arrayForProperty:property inRecord:person];
    NSString *pickedValue = (NSString *)[array objectAtIndex:identifier];

    NSString *firstName = [[ABContact contactWithRecord:person] firstname];
    NSString *lastName = [[ABContact contactWithRecord:person] lastname];
    NSString *fullName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ %@",firstName, lastName];

    if (chooseEmail)
    {
        txtToEmailAddress.text = fullName;
    }
    if (choosePhone)
    {
        txtCallPhoneNum.text = fullName;

    }
    if (chooseText)
    {
        txtTextNumbers.text = fullName;

    }

    return NO;

}
```

Please provide code sample with answers if possible. I very much appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few open source ideas you can take a look at that may help.
https://github.com/beat843796/HEBubbleView

https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/THContactPicker